# Add Product Selection to Admin Form

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, custom, adminform

I have developed a module for Magento 2 for Promotions.

I have a form for this which is working and contains basic information:

Title
Description
Price
Start Date
End Date

I now need to add "Products" to the promotion.

I have two tabs for this
[image: Promotion Form]

in the "Products" tab, I want to add a product selection form such as the one found in the categories page. like this:
[image: Product selection form]

I have searched through Magento SE and can't find the answer I am looking for.

Does anyone know a way of achieving this or a resource that I could read up on to learn how?

Comment: Are you using ui component form or normal form?

Comment: Hi Sukumar, i am using a normal form in PHP using $fieldSet->addField()